# Spring cloud skipper Cannot upload a package via REST API

Tags: spring-cloud-skipper

I am following a doc to upload a package into Skipper Server at https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-skipper/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#resources-package

Here is a package: [Helloworld](https://github.com/markpollack/skipper-sample-repository/blob/master/src/main/resources/static/repository/experimental/helloworld/helloworld-1.0.0.zip)

This is curl command as

```
$ curl 'http://localhost:7577/api/package/upload' -i -X POST \
    -H 'Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8' \
    -H 'Accept: application/json' \
    -F 'data=/home/user1/helloworld-1.0.0.zip'
```

But still cannot upload a package. Please help me what's correct to upload a package to Skipper via REST API.

P.s: By using a POSTMAN but It's also impossible.

Answer (score 0):

I found it how to do on old doc from spring team.
Post here if someone is needed.
https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-skipper/docs/1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/api-guide-resources.html#resources-package

Comment: Link is wellcome in this site. But you should add essential answer . Because link can be broken some time